# Increase Virtual Memory for Elasticsearch on GKE using cloud build

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created multi-node cluster on GKE and I was using this shell script for fixing the virtual memory on nodes [Set vm.max_map_count=262144 on the nodes of a GKE cluster #k8s](https://gist.github.com/thbkrkr/bc12a3457fd0f71c5a2106b11ce8801e). I want it to be executed in my cloud builder but it just returns Permission denied (publickey). on gcloud compute ssh execution. How can I fix it?

Comment: You may also want to consider using a different approach to setting vm.max_map_count.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71794098/5529712 for options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in the line

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone $(zone_by_node $node) $node -- sudo bash -c "'"$@"'"
```

set your username before node:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone $(zone_by_node $node) username@$node -- sudo bash -c "'"$@"'"
```

Your username is first part of your email before @.